# Arrangement of people in a line

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Question:
6 men and 3 women stand in a line. How many possible arrangements are there if no two of the women are standing next to each other?

My attempted solution:

Arrange the 6 men first in 6! Ways. Then arrange the 3 women in the 7 spaces in-between the men ( 7 P 3 ) so final answer is : 151,200

Comment: Your solution is correct.